# cannot bake CakePHP - permission denied while setting chmod +x for cake/console/cake - on NTFS mounted partition

Tags: php, linux, cakephp, ntfs, cakephp-bake

Just learning CakePHP and its Bake feature.

I tried to run

`../cake/console/cake bake`

from the `app` folder, but I get the error

`../cake/console/cake: Permission denied`

`chmod 777` nor `chmod +x` don't work. I still get permission denied.

Also tried setting permissions thru the Properties window, but when I check "Allow executing file as program", it changes right back to unchecked.

If it makes any difference, my `www/` folder is on an NTFS mounted partition. I used xampp on Windows before, and when I switched to Linux, `www/` is still in that NTFS partition, and I just had my Apache in Linux point to that folder.

Any suggestions?

Comment: i added ntfs and linux tags, since this sounds like a system problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case it helps anyone, what I ended up doing is that I changed Apache's `www` folder location to `~/www` and did my baking there. When I was done, I restored Apache's `www` folder to my NTFS partition, then copied into it my newly-baked application.

Answer (score 2):

the default linux ntfs driver cannot properly handle permissions settings on NTFS devices.

you need to look into the NTFS-3G drivers.

this might help
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11757/ntfs-under-linux